# pygame 'screen' not defined

Tags: python, pygame

Following the Python Crash Course, I copied this input and ran it with an error

```
import os
import pygame
def play_game():
    #Creates Screen
    resolution = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption('Game')
    #Colors the background
    bg_color = (230,230,230)
    #Starts the game
    while True:
        #Sets background color
        screen.fill(bg_color)
        #Looks for user inputs
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

                #updates the screen
                pygame.display.flip()



play_game()
```

The error reads:

> NameError: name 'screen' is not defined

How do I fix this? I believe I installed pygame and pip correctly.

Comment: Did you change the variable name? Was `resolution = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))` actually `screen= pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))` in the example..?

Comment: The name of your display surface (that `pygame.display.set_mode` returns) is `resolution` not `screen`. Just rename it to `screen`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the name 'screen'. Use the same variable to refer that in `screen.fill()`, change it to `resolution.fill()`

Answer (score -1):

Just change line five to :

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))
```